# How do I store date Variable in Postgres function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

So I am working to create a function that will delete the 1 month worth records from a table. The table is in postgres. As postgres does not have stored procedures I am trying to declare a function with the logic that will insert the 1 month records into a history table and then delete the records from the live table. I have the following code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeleteAndInsertTransaction(Integer)
    RETURNS Void
AS $Body$

SELECT now() into saveTime;

SELECT * INTO public.hist_table  
FROM (select * from public.live_table
    WHERE update < ((SELECT * FROM saveTime) - ($1::text || ' months')::interval)) as sub;

delete from public.live_table
where update < ((SELECT * FROM saveTime) - ($1::text || ' months')::interval);

DROP TABLE saveTime;     

$Body$
Language 'sql';
```

So the above code compiles fine but when I try to run it by invoking it :- `DeleteAndInsertTransaction(27)` it gives me an 
`Error: relation "savetime" does not exist` and I have no clue what is going on here.
 If I take out the `SELECT now() into saveTime;` out of the function bloc and declare it before invoking the function then it runs fine but I need to store the current date into a variable and use that as a constant for the insert and delete and this is going against a huge table and there could be significant time difference between the insert and deletes. Any pointers as to what is going on here ?

Comment: Postgrese does have stored procedures : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html but for what you are trying to do, a function is just as good.

Comment: *“postgres does not have stored procedures”* … as a_horse_with_no_name commented, the [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) was added to Postgres 11 and later. [Search to learn more](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=new+in+postgres+%22Create+Procedure%22&t=osx&ia=web), reading posts such as [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tech-preview-postgresql-11-create-procedure/) and [this](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-new-stored-procedures-postgresql-11).

Answer (score 2):

`select .. into ..` is the deprecated syntax for `create table ... as select ...` which [creates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) a **new** table.

So, `SELECT now() into saveTime;` actually creates a new table (named savetime), and is equivalent to: `create table savetime as select now();` - it's not storing something in a variable.

To store a value in a variable, you need to first [*declare*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) the variable, then you can [assign](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) the value. But you can only do that in PL/pgSQL, not SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeleteAndInsertTransaction(p_num_months integer)
  returns void
as
$Body$
declare
  l_now timestamp;
begin
  l_now := now();
  ...
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

To insert into an existing table you need

```
insert into public.hist_table  
select * 
from public.live_table.
```

To select the rows from the last x month, there is no need to store the current date and time in a variable to begin with. It's also easier to use `make_interval()` to generate an interval based on a specified unit.

You can simply use

```
select *
from live_table
where updated_at <= current_date - make_interval(mons => p_pum_months);
```

And as you don't need a variable, you can actually do all that with a `language sql` function.

So the function would look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DeleteAndInsertTransaction(p_num_months integer)
    RETURNS Void
AS 
$Body$

  insert into public.hist_table  
  select *
  from live_table
  where updated_at < current_date - make_interval(months => p_pum_months);

  delete from public.live_table
  where updated_at < current_date - make_interval(months => p_pum_months);

$Body$
Language sql;
```

Note that the language name is an identifier and should not be quoted.

---

You can actually do the DELETE and INSERT in a single statement:

```
with deleted as (
  delete from public.live_table
  where updated_at <= current_date - make_interval(months => p_pum_months)
  returning * 
)
insert into hist_table
select *
from deleted;
```